# Core Data's 'delete rule' for a relationship does not relay on a backend?

Tags: core-data

I use sqlite for the Core Data as a backend. It seems that when you set 'on delete' for an entity relationship as 'cascade' core data  does not use the backend to delete. Core data simple removes all relative data in a cycle. It gives me an extra delay when I try to remove object with a huge amount of relative objects. Firstly it fulfills all relative fault objects after that it deletes them one by one. I can see it from the log.

I thought that if I use sqlite as Core Data's backend the 'cascade' delete rule would be done with help of sqlite 'create table statement'.

Am I miss sth? Is there any possibility to force Core Data to use cascade deletion on a sqlite backend?

**UPD:**

As @Mundi has suggested. I've resolved it in the following way:

1. Set delete rule to 'No action' for entity (it is called Project)
   which has a lot of relative objects (over 10K)
2. Extend entity Project
   with prop isDeleted.
3. Instead of deleting I set Project.isDeleted to 1.
4. All views are filtered with predicated isDeleted eq 0.
5. Create a background task which run every 10 secs (tunable) and remove Projects with prop isDelete eq 1 and its relative objects

The background task does removing in the following way:

1. Exec fetch (isDeleted = 1) to get Projects to remove with setLimit eq 3 (tunable)
2. Exec **batch** fetches to get all relative objects to delete.
3. Delete all relative objects in a cycle + save after batch size. If here sth bad happens we can continue in another run. Here I even stop the task if user wants to close app.
4. Delete Project and save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, huge delete and insert operations can be a strain on performance. It does not matter if these deletes are caused by a delete rule or not.

The best solution is to delete the items yourself "manually". Override the method `willSave` in your parent managed object subclass, check for the `deleted` flag and delete the children yourself.

If there are many records to delete (check how many), you should be able to get rid of the performance issues by deleting **batches** of records (maybe a few hundred at a time) and saving after each batch.

Comment: Batching the deletions is an excellent idea, but keep in mind the atomicity tradeoffs inherent there. (What if the app crashes between a couple batches? They won't all get deleted.) iOS 8 has specific APIs for solving these kinds of problems: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-core-data-and-batch-updates--cms-22164

Comment: Good point. This could be addressed by searching for stray entities at app start to delete them. Besides, I am not sure Core Data will clean this up via the cascade rule in the interruption scenario you mention

Comment: @AndyRiordan I hope that I've overcome the problem with crashes between batches, see the updates.